# Refresh single div with .#div.load(scriptpage.php) not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to refresh a single div's content (in-game chat) every X amount of seconds or minutes with this simple code

Now the problem seems to be that it never refreshes or loads the other page. I have been combing through SO and other coding sites and believe me, there are a TON of posts on SO about this very function, I have copy pasted, hand written, and edited other's codes but nothing seems to be working. BTW, I have no experience with Ajax, js, or jquery. Only HTML, CSS, and some PHP.

**HTML**
 I know I don't need the actual code there and could easily leave the div blank for the script to populate the div.

```
<div id="chat">
    <?php
    $id = XXXX; //your service ID
    $api_key = 'XXXX'; //your CBSM API key
    $act = 2; //action #2 indicates retrieval of chat
    $limit = 150; //number of chat results - max of 500
    $offset = 0; //optional starting point.. to retrieve past messages
    $response = file_get_contents('https://api.envul.com/?s='.$id.'&api='.$api_key.'&act='.$act.'&limit='.$limit);
       if($response != '') {
       $chat_messages = explode("<br>", $response);
         foreach($chat_messages as $chat_message)
           {
              echo $chat_message; 
              echo '<hr>';  
           }
        } else { 
           echo 'Error';
        }



   ?>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function loadlink(){
$('#chat').load('chat.php'() {
     $(this).unwrap();
});
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
</script>
```

**PHP Script on separate page**

```
<?php
$id = XXXX; //your service ID
$api_key = 'XXXX'; //your CBSM API key
$act = 2; //action #2 indicates retrieval of chat
$limit = 150; //number of chat results - max of 500
$offset = 0; //optional starting point.. to retrieve past messages
$response = file_get_contents('https://api.envul.com/?s='.$id.'&api='.$api_key.'&act='.$act.'&limit='.$limit);
  if($response != '') {
     $chat_messages = explode("<br>", $response);
     foreach($chat_messages as $chat_message)
     {
        echo $chat_message; 
        echo '<hr>';  
     }
  } else { 
     echo 'Error';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Nevermind, the issue has been resolved! Not deleting though as per the DO NO DELETE request.

Comment: gr8.then add the solution as **SOLUTION** and add `[Solved]` in title.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware that it was preferred to add [SOLVED] to the title. Haven't seen that convention used much.

Comment: most people don't add it. Adding it will make people not waste their time as the OP is very long and solution is in comment. generally people get frustrated by seeing this type of posts when they visit to answer the post. :-)

Comment: Adding "solved" is [not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/actively-prevent-this-in-title-solved) the preferred solution at all.

Comment: @EricD. Thank you. Should probably not listen to people when they tell me things like that from now on unless they have a link to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since solved the issue. The line `$(this).unwrap();` was causing the position of the refreshed content to be thrown off somehow. It was being placed behind another div.

Removing such line fixed my issue.